# Calling redux actions without bindActionCreator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to store the GPS position of the user in my redux-store. To get the coords I use this:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( (data) => {
  //
}, null, {
    timeout: 60000,
    distanceFilter: 10
});
```

I have a reducer for the position:

```
import createReducer from '../lib/createReducer'
import * as types from '../actions/types'

export const position = createReducer({}, {
  [types.SET_POSITION](state, action) {
    return {
        latitude: action.latitude,
        longitude: action.longitude
    };;
  }
})
```

And an action:

```
import * as types from './types'

export function watchPosition() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

        ???
  }
}

export function setPosition({ latitude, longitude }) {
  console.log('JA');
  return {
    type: types.SET_POSITION,
    latitude,
    longitude
  }
}
```

I want to init this watchPosition in my Home-Screen. I don't bind the actions there (no connect() ).

How to call this action and init the reducer when new position is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You czn import your store object in your commponent or another executive place of code and then use `store.dispatch(() => { return{ type: ACTION_TYPE, payload: data } })`.

or you can use [reduxThunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware to touch the store: `store.dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPE, payload: data })`.

Hope this help you